# Android Launching Contacts Application

Tags: android, android-intent, contactscontract

I wanna launch the Contacts application from my application Activity. I am not able to understand how to do it.

```
    Button contact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contact);
    contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i4 = new Intent();
            i4.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i4.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            i4.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/phone");
            startActivity(i4);
        }
    });
```

Error:

> [image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
void showContacts()
{
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.contacts", "com.android.contacts.DialtactsContactsEntryActivity"));
    i.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    i.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
    startActivity(i);
}
```

This should work in everything from Donut through to Gingerbread: not sure about Honeycomb.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch a contact Picker:

```
public void doLaunchContactPicker(View view) {  
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  
            Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);  
}
```

Or you can also launch the app:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.Intents.html

Comment: i wanna launch the application not the picker

Comment: i am using 2.2 version and Contacts is decapitated

Comment: see ContactsContract: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html