# Launching an application from onReceive() of BroadcastReceiver in Android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

Is it possible to Launch an application or activity from `onRecieve()` of a `BroadcastReceiver` in Android?
I want to launch an activity when the wi-Fi is turned on.
If it is possible please explain how to do that. I am expecting a sample code for that..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are tons of examples here... you just need the class name.

[Android Launching Contacts Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787088/android-launching-contacts-application)

[Start Activity inside onReceive BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468463/start-activity-inside-onreceive-broadcastreceiver)