# How do I open the default contacts screen on Android?

Tags: android

How do I open the default contacts screen on Android?

Comment: If at all i tried i wouldn't ask a question. Since i am in a need i asked it without surfing. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Have a look at this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-using-the-contact-picker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there and welcome to StackOverflow AND Android development.

In order to open the contacts screen, you need to capture the `OnClick` event for your button and create an intent to open the contact screen.

Something like this:

```
Button myButton = (Button) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
myButton..setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

If you want to do something with the contact that the user selects, use a `startActivityForResult` instead and overwrite the `onActivityResult` method (read more about that [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29).

Some similar answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787088/android-launching-contacts-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955783/how-do-i-open-contacts-when-i-click-a-button-defined-in-main-xml)!

Good luck!

Comment: Why is it ACTION_PICK and not ACTION_VIEW?

Answer (score 1):

**code**

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/"));
startActivity(i);
```